# Are there any implementations of a graph crossing algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, software, implementation

This is much more focused version of this question:

[Are there good implementations for easy subclasses of NP-hard graph problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6186/are-there-good-implementations-for-easy-subclasses-of-np-hard-graph-problems)

Computing the [graph-crossing number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCrossingNumber.html) $cr(G)$ for a simple graph is known to be NP-complete. A quick literature review shows some suggested algorithms for computing if $cr(G)<k$. Are they any active implementations available?

Already checked: [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html), [CGAL_Boost](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html), [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/), [graph_tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/)

Comment: Depending on the definition of "available". Check http://webcompute.ae.uni-jena.de/

Comment: @someone this link is broken unfortunately

Comment: Looks like it might have moved to: http://crossings.uos.de/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slow brute-force implementation of the graph crossing number
was added to Sage in

- [Sage Trac ticket 24216: Add crossing number of a graph](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24216)
- [Github issue: Add crossing number of a graph #24216](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/24216)

which was closed 2018-01-05, and merged in Sage 8.2.beta3.

Comment: This is great, thanks! For completeness, it looks like they implemented the algorithm in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.03854.pdf